# How to configure Celestia to work with a spherical mirror projection on a dome

Tags: software

I find hints around the web, e.g. http://www.cosmodome.net/mirrordome.php that Celestia can be projected on a dome using a spherical mirror projection configuration.

The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to configure Celestia to warp the generated image, so it can be used in such a projection setup.

For Stellarium\Nightshade I found some references, e.g. [from spherical projection guru, Paul Bourke,](http://paulbourke.net/dome/stellarium/) and I expected to find similar resources for Celestia.

1. Can Celestia be configured for a spherical mirror projection system?
2. Can you point me to documentation on how to set up Celestia for a spherical mirror projection system?
3. Is there a way to warp Celestia with 3rd party tools and then project the images?

Comment: Maybe try contacting this guy? http://www.bisque.com/sc/forums/t/8967.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors preferred approach to Stellarium and Celestia for spherical mirror projection is as follows
http://paulbourke.net/dome/fishwarp/#screen
One operates in dual display mode, the projector is connected to the secondary display. The fisheye is copied and warped onto the secondary display. The operator has the benefit of seeing the unwarped image on the primary display. This option wasn't ideal in the past but is more sensible now that current Macs have retina displays. This obviously work for any other program that supports fisheye.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to Paul Bourke's page on [screen capture](http://paulbourke.net/dome/screencapture/)

> While only the commercial version of Celestia supports fisheye, it also does not support warping of fisheye (although some versions have been created that do). The solution outlined here has been tested successfully with a fisheye supported version of Celestia.

It seems that Celestia in its free version is not providing any support for dome projection and the commercial version requires tweaking before you can use its support for fisheye projection and convert it to Spherical Mirror Projection.

Comment: The web page you link to is dated October 2010, so whilst this *may* still be true, it is hardly definitive.